# Stripe webhook is GET request (not POST) and always 404 response

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-cashier

I'm integrating Stripe webhooks in my development environment (in Stripe test mode) and have confirmed that all requests are coming in as GET requests, not POST requests as the documentation states. Am I missing something?

Laravel routes:

**Yep:**

```
Route::get(
    'stripe/webhook',
    '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook'
);
```

**Nope:**

```
Route::post(
    'stripe/webhook',
    '\Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController@handleWebhook'
);
```

Also, for some reason even though my application is returning a 200 response, and Stripe is seeing that, Stripe is saying it failed with a 404 response:

[image: Screenshot from dashboard.stripe.com]

[image: Screenshot from dashboard.stripe.com]

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stripe Webhooks are (as are pretty much all webhooks everywhere) *always* POST requests, you will never receive a GET request as a webhook. Please post your routes and related controllers as the issue will be there somewhere.

Comment: @Jason Post updated with routes.

Comment: Try ngrok for example locally. You will _see_ the request come in and be able to confirm it's a POST and not a GET

Comment: Try using tools like https://beeceptor.com if you want to debug if (a) these events are coming from Stripe or not, (b) inspect the POST payload

Answer (score 1):

A quick follow-up and solution to this issue for future reference: Since this is a development/staging site it is protected by basic auth, and so I had (attempted to) disabled basic auth on the /stripe/webhook route in the Nginx config:

```
location /stripe/webhook {
    auth_basic "off";
}
```

However, that was lacking the specificity of a "try_files" directive and therefore, for some reason, converting the request from POST to GET. Here is the updated and correct config:

```
location /stripe/webhook {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    auth_basic "off";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing just one thing. You forgot to exclude stripe routes from CSRF verification.

In `Middlewares/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```